# Looking for a Bug-workflow VS Extension

Tags: visual-studio-2010, bugzilla

My company will move to TFS *sometime* next year but is currently relying on a patchwork solution involving Bugzilla (2.2), code commenting and build-user inboxes for managing bugfix workflow.  I've been looking at writing some VS extensions (or using code snippets) to help automate and standardize this.  I currently have a code snippet for standardized comments along with the "email code snippet" extension for emailing comments (which include build instructions) off to build-user inboxes.  It's better than we had, but well short efficient.

The question:  Are there any extensions, combination of extensions, or combinations of available extension code out there that does this sort of thing.  Using visual Studio 2010 but constrained to Bugzilla 2.2.  This will be a < 1yr solution, so a minimum of cost and complexity is a must.